# Transfer data from one class to another

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to port an Android App to ios. It's been awhile since ive done c/c++ and i am completly new to objective c, anyway: I started with a single view "ViewController". There i have a button which creates data in ViewController.mm. For simplicity lets say its just a double.

ViewController.mm:

```
double myDouble = 13;
```

I have a Button which launches the next view like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TrimView" owner:self options:nil]; 
[self.view addSubview:TrimView];
```

On the "TrimView" i want to graphically display the data which i got in ViewController.mm, so the double myDouble.
I followed this small tutorial in order to be able to draw lines:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

I use this code to draw the line:
TrimView.mm:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);

}
```

I am kinda stuck and i am looking for opinions now how i should go on. For simplicity lets say i just want to start the line which is drawn in trimView.mm at position myDouble. How would i transfer it from ViewController to trimView ?

My problem now is that i dont have something like

```
TrimView tf;
```

in ViewController.mm where i could do something like:

```
TrimView.setMyDouble(myDouble);
```

I just have (like said above):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TrimView" owner:self options:nil]; 
[self.view addSubview:TrimView];
```

After reading the Answer i tried this:

```
TrimView *nextView =  [[TrimView alloc] initWithNib=@"TrimView" bundle=nil];
```

But got this: "No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'alloc'"

TrimView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TrimView: UIView

@property(nonatomic) double *myDouble;

@end
```

Comment: Well, how would you transfer the value of one class member variable to another class in Java?

Comment: To be honest, i learned c then i taught myself android/java. In android i have 1 Class with 6000 lines of code. I am trying to get this whole opp thing now, but it is hard if you are used to code this way.

Comment: c++ tag: if this can be done with c++ or objective-c i wouldnt care which way to use

Comment: @juanchopanza it's strictly objc and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, with ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB.

To pass a `double` value from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB we would do the following :

1) in ViewControllerB.h create a property for the BOOL

```
@property(nonatomic) double *myDouble;
```

2) in ViewControllerA, include ViewControllerB :

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
```

3) When you want to load the view, you need to set the property in ViewControllerB before you push it onto navigation stack :

```
ViewControllerB *nextView = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib=@"ViewControllerB" bundle=nil];
nextView.myDouble = myDouble;
[self pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

This will set your double in ViewControllerB to the value you want.

In your case, you may change the last line to `[self.view addSubview:nextView];`.

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have another TrimView.h/m somewhere in your project folder ? Just in case you copied it at some point and it's creating a conflict... You can still try cleaning the project, and exiting/relaunching Xcode.

Comment: sorry i thought it was fixed, but it isnt so here it is again: No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'alloc' at ViewControllerB *nextView = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib=@"ViewControllerB" bundle=nil]; will check for the files as you said

Comment: nope didnt help. will add the whole TrimView.h in the question

Answer (score 0):

You create a double property on TrimView - read up on properties. TrimView would be created, then configured by setting the properties it needs, and when it runs it can get those properties easily.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double myDouble;
```

Comment: I guess my problem isnt really clear. I am not creating a class in ViewController, like TrimView tf, where i could later do something like tf.setMyDouble.